# I have been refused admission into US whilst on a ESTA under 217 can I still get a tourist visa?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, denial-of-entry

I travelled to US on an esta. I got refused under section 219 because i was going to study but mistakenly thought i could get student visa in us. Then got denied student visa in embassy though unclear why. Can i still get a B2 visa? What do i need to know? I have a student visa in another country. Ticket back to that country and an invitation for a wedding in US which is reason i want to go now.

Comment: After twice trying to enter to study, how will you convince US Immigration that now you just want to be a tourist?

Comment: Do you mean 219 (terrorist organization) or 291 (burden of proof)? Big difference there.

Comment: You can try, but it's unlikely that the outcome will be any different.

Comment: It has been over a year. I was denied a student visa now Im applying for a tourist visa.

Comment: "Then got denied student visa in embassy though unclear why": why is it unclear?  What information did they give you?

Comment: @JonCuster: I'm guessing they mean INA 217, the section that provides for the Visa Waiver Program

Answer (score 2):

You have already been refused entry at the U.S. border — and you have also been denied a U.S. visa at the embassy.

It's very unlikely that you will get a U.S. tourist visa to attend the wedding (assuming it's within 1 year). The U.S. government already believes you are at risk of not following the rules for the student visa (and that reasoning would likely carry over for other nonimmigrant visas, including tourist visas). You need to wait for at least a few years before applying for another U.S. visa — and when you do apply, you must show strong ties (job in home country, family, etc.) to get a tourist and/or student visa.

I'm sorry that you're going through this — the U.S. immigration system can be very difficult. You'll have a stronger chance in a couple of years if you can show strong ties to your home country.

Comment: "the US already believes you are not a genuine visitor": in the first case, the government believed that because it was admittedly true: the traveler was seeking to enter for a different purpose.  In the second case, it is unclear why the visa was refused.  Perhaps it was for another reason such as incorrect or missing paperwork from the academic sponsor.  This would have no direct relevance to a tourist visa.